# Database trigger on update, remove, create

Tags: django, django-signals

I want some code to be executed after every change in the database in a specific table. Meaning, if an entry was `inserted, removed or updated`.

I found this https://stackoverflow.com/a/15712353/2813152 using django signals. Is this the recommended way for this?

Can I use it for any changes at this table? Not just when an instance is saved?

Can the code run async in the background?

Answer (score 0):

Django signals are not asynchronous. But you can trigger a background job via a signal with e.g. [celery](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/django/index.html) if you have code that takes some more time to complete.

As per [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/signals/#post-save), the `django.db.models.signals.post_save` signal has an argument `created` which you can use to find out if an object has been added or changed.

Get an overview of all [built-in model signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/signals/) in Django.